# How do i write these script together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few script that does the same thing, but seems unnecessary to have the load separate. how do I write these together?

Scripts:

```
$('document').ready(
function() {
$('.linksRight').insertAfter('.treemenu');
$('.treemenu').insertBefore('.linksRight');
});

$('document').ready(
function() {
$('#newbutton').insertAfter('.searching');
$('.searching').insertBefore('#newbutton');
});

$('document').ready(
function() {
$('#filterbox').insertAfter('.itembox.smallbox');
$('.itembox.smallbox').insertBefore('#filterbox');
});
```

Comment: Huh.... Why writing 3 different `$('document').ready(.....);`.. ??

Comment: That was the op question :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some of things to be noticed:

1. `$('document')` should not be inside `''` quotes.
2. You can use single doc ready and put everything together.

---

Try the below one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.linksRight').insertAfter('.treemenu');
    $('.treemenu').insertBefore('.linksRight');
    $('#newbutton').insertAfter('.searching');
    $('.searching').insertBefore('#newbutton');
    $('#filterbox').insertAfter('.itembox.smallbox');
    $('.itembox.smallbox').insertBefore('#filterbox');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
$('.linksRight').insertAfter('.treemenu');
$('.treemenu').insertBefore('.linksRight');
$('#newbutton').insertAfter('.searching');
$('.searching').insertBefore('#newbutton');
$('#filterbox').insertAfter('.itembox.smallbox');
$('.itembox.smallbox').insertBefore('#filterbox');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').ready(
 function() {
  $('#newbutton #filterbox .linksRight').insertAfter('.treemenu .searching     .itembox.smallbox');
   $('.searching .treemenu .itembox.smallbox').insertBefore('.linksRight .filterbox #newbutton');
 });
```

hope this helps